# Need help in identifying SMA package component

Tags: diodes, components, surface-mount, tvs, bipolar

I have a problem with identifying a certain element in the SMA housing, which in my opinion has a marking that is inconsistent with what is given in the datasheet (the datasheet which I selected based on observations).

The element looks like in the photo below:

[image]

You can see the letter marking "CP" here. This would suggest that in the datasheet from the link (page 2):

https://www.littelfuse.com/media?resourcetype=datasheets&itemid=13c2a823-03b8-4d1f-9ddc-9b44670aed9d&filename=littelfuse-tvs-diode-smaj-datasheet

this will be the SMAJ36A element. However, it turns out that the SMAJ36A element is unipolar, while the element from the photo is clearly bipolar (lack of a characteristic line defining polarity).

My question is whether it could be some other element or do you know whether Littelfuse designates any of its other product lines with similar letter abbreviations?

Comment: Did you verify the dimensions of the package, that it is indeed SMA? For example the SMBJ36CA is bidirectional marked **CP**.

Comment: How do you know that the device is meant to be what it is (uni or bi)?

Comment: I appreciate the tight cropping but did the original really have to be three megapixels of blur? The actual resolution is so low even the thumbnail can be reduced considerably...

Answer (score 2):

You got the package wrong. This is a [Littlefuse SMBJ36CA](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2304140030_Littelfuse-SMBJ36CA_C83326.pdf) which is a bipolar TVS diode.

If we compare SMAJ36A and SMBJ36CA we can clearly see that it's the latter in your picture:

SMAJ36A:
[image]

SMBJ36CA:
[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com))

Comment: You're right! A width of this element is about 3.5 mm, so looks like SMB package. Thanks!